# "7" instead of "Sunday" in the weekday timeline diagram

Tags: looker-studio

I would like to show the chronological distribution of the user flows on the individual days of the week in a timeline diagram. No data is displayed for Sunday.

Upon further investigation, I found that Analytics passes "7" as the value to Looker Studio instead of the name "Sunday" as it does for the other days of the week. This problem occurs with all newly set up data sources (in the last two months). Does anyone have an idea how we can solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you go into your data source, resource > manage added data sources > click edit on the relevant data source the issue is with > add a field:

```
    CASE
    WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(DAY OF THE WEEK, '1') THEN 'Monday'
    WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(DAY OF THE WEEK, '2') THEN 'Tuesday'
    WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(DAY OF THE WEEK, '3') THEN 'Wednesday'
    WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(DAY OF THE WEEK, '4') THEN 'Thursday'
    WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(DAY OF THE WEEK, '5') THEN 'Friday'
    WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(DAY OF THE WEEK, '6') THEN 'Saturday'
    WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(DAY OF THE WEEK, '7') THEN 'Sunday' 
    END
```

DAY OF THE WEEK is where you input the variable which the days are under. Be sure to create a unique field name and use the variable in your visualisation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select Date as Dimension and edit field

   [image: Edit Date dimension]
2. Select dropdown from Data Type

   [image: Click dropdown where it says Date]
3. Hover over Date & Time and choose Day of Week from the options

   [image: Choose Day of Week from dropdown options]